# IMAP body command. How to get just the text or html part of the body?

Tags: c#, imap

I have a query regarding the FETCH...BODY[...] command.

What is the best way to just obtain the text or html part of the body? I thought that the BODY[TEXT] command would do this but it is also returning attachments etc which is severely affecting performance.

Currently, this is what I do (C# code):

```
        if (contentType != null)
        {
            switch (contentType.ToLower())
            {
                case "multipart/alternative":
                case "text/plain":
                case "text/html":
                    body = " BODY[1]";
                    break;
                case "multipart/related":
                case "multipart/signed":
                    body = " BODY[1.1]";
                    break;
                case "multipart/report":
                    body = " BODY[1]";
                    break;
                case "multipart/mixed":
                    if (mail.MailBody.TextBodyPartCount == 1)
                        body = " BODY[1]";
                    else if (mail.MailBody.TextBodyPartCount == 2)
                    {
                        if (bodyType == BodyType.Plain)
                            body = " BODY[1.1]";
                        else
                            body = " BODY[1.2]";
                    }
                    else
                        body = " BODY[1]";
                    break;
                default:
                    body = " BODY[1]";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            body = " BODY[1]";
        }
```

This works most of the time, but in some cases it returns NIL. Sorry if I have left any details out, but please do ask!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email messages are stored in MIME format - it allows creating a tree structure with unlimited depth.
You can't assume how this tree structure looks like by only checking content-type.

You should use BODYSTRUCTURE to recreate the tree structure without downloading the message, and after that you can decide which parts you need to fetch.

Comment: Thanks for you response. But how do I do that? How do I fetch particular body parts?

Comment: @Umair Used BODYSTRUCTURE command (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501)  You can also try Mail.dll: http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/